# Using python load images from directory and reshape

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I want to load same images from directory and reshape them using reshape function using python.

How can i do this?

Comment: Load the images from a directory, then reshape them with Python.

Comment: I am asking how can i do it. do you have any tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) installed and assuming that with "reshape" you actually mean "resize", the following code should load all images from the directory `/foo/bar`, resize them to 64x64 and add them to the list `images`:

```
import os
from scipy import ndimage, misc

images = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/foo/bar"):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = ndimage.imread(filepath, mode="RGB")
            image_resized = misc.imresize(image, (64, 64))
            images.append(image_resized)
```

If you need a numpy array (to call `reshape`) then just add `images = np.array(images)` at the end (with `import numpy as np` at the start).

Comment: misc.imresize is now deprecated.  The docs recommend using Pillow instead.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `os.walk()` to traverse the directory for images.
2. Load images using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/)
3. Use Image.getdata to get a list of values
4. Pass that list to numpy.reshape

There's a lot I skipped over. You might have to use a different method than getdata from Pillow but you didn't give a lot of context.

Comment: could you give an example for step 4

Comment: Just following the documentation from [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) which says it takes an array like object. Pillow's Image.getdata appears to return something like this.